# How can I convert a Vec<Option<EmbedField>> to an Option<Vec<discord_webhook::EmbedField>>?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() {
    pub struct EmbedField {
        name: String,
        value: String,
        inline: bool
    }

    let fields: Vec<Option<EmbedField>> = vec![
        Some(EmbedField{ name: "Nats".to_string(), value: name, inline: true}),
        Some(EmbedField{ name: "LPB".to_string(), value: lpb, inline: true})
    ];
}
```

(not my complete code)

I want to convert it into an `Option<Vec<discord_webhook::EmbedField>>` because to return it I need to convert it into `Option<Vec<discord_webhook::EmbedField>>`.

The structure is from https://github.com/soulflyman/discord-webhook.

Comment: When there is a `None` inside, do you want to remove it or do you want the whole result to be `None`?

Comment: If you want to remove `None` items, see @cdhowie's answer. If you want the whole result to be `None`, use `into_iter().collect()`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=31e5b5ba116adebc88379d981dbae96d).

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially unwrap the inner Option values and remove None values using `filter_map()`:

```
let fields = fields.into_iter().filter_map(|v| v).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

This will result in a `Vec<EmbedField>`.  If you really need the outer `Option` value then you can wrap this expression in `Some()`.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ab1c000293ebb98d5f648eb814745ef9))

Comment: You can also replace `|v| v` with `std::convert::identity`.

Answer (score 0):

`fields.into_iter().collect::<Option<Vec<_>>()` will return `None` if any `None` existed in the original vec, else `Some([unwrapped vec elems])`.